# Self-refering table. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have another question. I don't seem to fully grasp the concept.

I have a table:

```
EMPLOYEES

| EMP_NO | APELLIDO | OFFICE | DIRECTOR | START_DATE | SALARY | COMMISSION | DEP_NO |
```

I have to obtain data of employees who's OFFICE is 'DIRECTOR' (easy, but... ) and I also have to include a column that would return full salary (salary+commission) of all the employees who are theirs subordinates.

Now I know that I need to 'copy' the table so I am able to make it to refer to itself (EMPLOYEES e1, EMPLOYEES e2 etc.). But I am getting really worked up in that obtaining total of salary of those subordinates.

Any thoughts?
(pls help)

**EDIT**

Sorry guys, true. My fault. OK, so here are some sample data:

```
+--------+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+--------+
| EMP_NO | SURNAME  | OFFICE     | DIRECTOR | START_DATE | SALARY  |COMMISSION| DEP_NO |
+--------+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+--------+
|   7499 | ALONSO   |SALESPERSON |     7698 | 1981-02-23 | 1400.00 |   400.00 |     30 |
|   7521 | LOPEZ    | EMPLOYEE   |     7782 | 1981-05-08 | 1350.50 |     NULL |     10 |
|   7654 | MARTIN   |SALESPERSON |     7698 | 1981-09-28 | 1500.00 |  1600.00 |     30 |
|   7698 | GARRIDO  | DIRECTOR   |     7839 | 1981-05-01 | 3850.12 |     NULL |     30 |
|   7782 | MARTINEZ | DIRECTOR   |     7839 | 1981-06-09 | 2450.00 |     NULL |     10 |
|   7839 | REY      |    CEO     |     NULL | 1981-11-17 | 6000.00 |     NULL |     10 |
|   7844 | CALVO    |SALESPERSON |     7698 | 1981-09-08 | 1800.00 |     0.00 |     30 |
|   7876 | GIL      |  ANALIST   |     7782 | 1982-05-06 | 3350.00 |     NULL |     20 |
|   7900 | JIMENEZ  | EMPLOYEE   |     7782 | 1983-03-24 | 1400.00 |     NULL |     20 |
+--------+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+--------+
```

What I need to achieve now is to return table with details of employees GARRIDO and MARTINEZ (EMP_NO 7698 and 7782) along with additional column that would contain total salary of all theirs direct subordinates. Something like that:

```
+--------+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+--------+-----------+
| EMP_NO | SURNAME  | OFICIO     | DIRECTOR | FECHA_ALTA | SALARIO | COMISION | DEP_NO | TOTAL_EMP |
+--------+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+--------+-----------+    
|   7698 | GARRIDO  | DIRECTOR   |     7839 | 1981-05-01 | 3850.12 |     NULL |     30 |   6700    |
|   7782 | MARTINEZ | DIRECTOR   |     7839 | 1981-06-09 | 2450.00 |     NULL |     10 |  1350.50  |
+--------+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected output

Comment: Are you only looking for immediate subordinates or do you need to get total salary for all of their subordinates plus all of their subordinates' subordinates, etc.?

Comment: How is the director linked to the employee? Is it the `DIRECTOR` column?

Comment: Chin Leung, Director is also an employee so his emp_no is placed in DIRECTOR column of his subordinates. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do it. You just need to `JOIN` to the other rows that you need, then it's a simple matter of grouping to get the aggregate amount that you want.

```
SELECT
    D.emp_no,
    D.apellido,    -- Why is there one column named in Spanish and the rest in English?
    D.office,
    D.director,
    D.start_date,
    D.salary,
    D.commission,
    D.dep_no,
    SUM(COALESCE(S.salary, 0) + COALESCE(S.commission, 0)) AS subordinates_compensation
FROM
    Employees D
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees S ON S.director = D.emp_no
WHERE
    D.office = 'Director'
GROUP BY
    D.emp_no,
    D.apellido,
    D.office,
    D.director,
    D.start_date,
    D.salary,
    D.commission,
    D.dep_no
```

Comment: Because I was a bit sloppy and did not translate that one :)  Thank you, I am just trying it out now.

Comment: OK. Thank you, that works indeed. I just need to exclude the director's salary. :) Perfect, thank you (I am so not ready for the exam).

Comment: Yes, if the director's row points back to itself (`director = emp_no`) then you can add a condition in the `JOIN` clause to eliminate that row (`AND S.emp_no <> D.emp_no`)